# функция должна работать, пока не будет нажата кнопка

Tags: c++, qt, gui

Здравствйте. Есть программа, C++ QT, задача такова, что у меня есть эмуляция процесса зарядки аккумулятора, который срабатывает после нажатия кнопки, также существуют ещё две кнопки: "прекращение зарядки" и "ускоренная зарядка". Вопрос, собственно, в том, что при нажатии кнопки "запуск зарядки" или "ускоренная зарядка", остальные кнопки блокируются, до завершения работы функции зарядки, что делает невозможным принудительное прекращение этой самой зарядки, используя кнопку "Прекращение зарядки". Как дать пользователю возможность использовать остальные кнопки во время процесса работы функции её принудительного завершения? Сама зарядка происходит через цикл do {} while(); с установленными задержками увеличения уровня заряда.

```
void MainWindow::charge()
{
    int krya;

    double i = 0;
    double dt = 1;
    if (currentVoltage <= (minVoltage + (maxVoltage - minVoltage) / 5) && (currentTime < needTime))
        do
        {
            currentVoltage += (amperage * voltage * 3 * dt)/k; // тут должна быть функция зарядки конкретного аккумулятора .

            Sleep(1000 * dt);

            i += 10 * dt;
            currentVolume = (currentVoltage - minVoltage) * k;
            currentTime = currentVolume / consumptions;

            QString output2 {"%время зарядки: "},
                    output3,
                    output4 {"мc\nтекущее напряжение акб: "},
                    output5;

            krya = 100 * (currentVoltage-minVoltage) / (maxVoltage-minVoltage) ;
            output3.setNum(i);
            output5.setNum(currentVoltage);

            ui->progressBar->setValue(krya);
            ui->progressBar->value();
            ui->main_label->setText(output2 + output3 + output4 + output5);


        } while (currentVoltage < (minVoltage + (maxVoltage - minVoltage) / 5 )&&(currentTime<needTime));
```

Comment: Запускать цикл зарядки в отдельном потоке

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [QFutureWatcher](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html) и [QtConcurrent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtconcurrentrun.html) для запуска в отдельном потоке, это поможет не блокировать основной поток

Сделал небольшой примерчик. В качестве future выступает [QtConcurrent::map](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtconcurrentmap.html). В основном окне расположены 2 кнопки **start** и **stop**, и **Label**. Методы **onStartBtnClicked** и **onStopBtnClicked** обрабатывают нажатие соответствующих кнопок.

По изменению progressValue устанавливается значение в **Label**

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFutureWatcher>
#include <QFuture>
#include <QtConcurrent>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void onStartBtnClicked();
    void onStopBtnClicked();

    void setValue(const int &value);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QFutureWatcher<void> watcher;
    const int iterations = 1000;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(&watcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::progressValueChanged, this, &MainWindow::setValue);

    connect(ui->startBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onStartBtnClicked);
    connect(ui->stopBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onStopBtnClicked);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::onStartBtnClicked()
{
    QList<int> list;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i+=5)
        list.append(i);

    std::function<void(int&)> spin = [](int &iteration) {
            qDebug() << "iteration" << iteration << "in thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();
            QThread::sleep(1);
        };

    watcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::map(list, spin));
}


void MainWindow::onStopBtnClicked()
{
    watcher.cancel();
    watcher.waitForFinished();
}

void MainWindow::setValue(const int &value)
{
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(value));
}
```

Comment: Плохая идея, из отдельного потока не получится дергать методы gui объектов

Comment: @BeardedBeaver и как тогда вывести работу функции в отдельный поток?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver  Почему же не получится, Если использовать QThread, то можно дергать методы с помощью сигналов/слотов

Comment: @RafaelF. вот об этом стоило написать в ответе, это важная особенность

Comment: @BeardedBeaver у QFuture есть такой метод int QFuture::progressValue() const

Comment: Можно с его помощью изменять значение в GUI

Comment: Зачем вы пишете об этом в комментарии? Дополните ответ чтобы он максимально отражал то, что необходимо сделать для решения вопроса

Comment: @RafaelF. а можете более конкретно подсказать, что именно нужно сделать? На разных других сайтах я увидел методы с созданием отдельного объекта для реализации необходимого метода в отдельном потоке, но в таком случае я совершенно не понимаю, как дёргать методы GUI

Comment: @SpectreCat Сделаю более подробный пример, ожидайте

Comment: @SpectreCat Обновил ответ, если что не понятно спрашивайте

Comment: @RafaelF. не совсем понимаю всё-таки, как мне вывести мой метод в параллельный поток, ибо там всё же тип функции void, а не int&, который требуется для метода QtConcurrent::map(), да и как возвращать что-либо не из лямбда-функции в таком случае, я тоже не совсем понимаю. Хотя может, я вообще пытаюсь залезть не в те дебри

Comment: @SpectreCat  Определите свой метод по аналогии с std::function<void(int&)> spin.

Comment: int &iteration нужен для подсчета количества итераций и изменения progressValue.

Comment: Возвращение результата по завершению работы функции тоже реализуемо, читайте документацию, у QFuture есть метод result.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо большое, посмотрю

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант это в пределах одного потока эмулировать зарядку с помощью таймера:

```
QTimer* timer; // объявляем таймер как поле класса вашего окна

// где-то в конструкторе окна:
timer  = new QTimer(this);  
timer->setInterval(1000); // это вместо вашего sleep
// раз в секунду обновляем заряд
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::charge); 
timer->start();

// в методе charge не делаем цикл, а обрабатываем только один шаг
ui->progressBar->setValue(krya);
ui->progressBar->value();
ui->main_label->setText(output2 + output3 + output4 + output5);

// в конце проверяем, если зарядка закончена, останавливаем таймер
if (currentVoltage < (minVoltage + (maxVoltage - minVoltage) / 5 )&&(currentTime<needTime))
    timer->stop();
```

Остановку зарядки делаем так же остановкой таймера.

Второй вариант это действительно запустить функцию `charge` в отдельном потоке, но вместо прямого управления элементами гуя бросать из цикла сигналы с обновленными параметрами, а сигнал присоединить к слоту обновления. И придется попрыгать с остановкой, видимо делать атомарный флажок остановки и проверять его в цикле зарядки.